# Powershell ConvertTo-Json with a collection of values

Tags: arrays, json, rest, powershell, collections

I am trying to create the following Json to be passed as the body for a ReST request using the Invoke-WebRequest cmdLet

```
{  
   "fields":{  
      "summary":"Execution Monday, August 27, 2018 3:24 PM",
      "project":{  
         "id":10401
      },
      "issuetype":{  
         "id":10103
      },
      "customfield_10527":[  
         "IC-54829",
         "IC-54830"
      ],
      "customfield_10539":[  
         "IC-54831"
      ]
   }
}
```

Using the following powershell

```
Write-Output 'Creating Test Execution'
$dateString = Get-Date -Format f
$createTestExecutionBody = @{
    fields = @{
        summary = 'Execution ' + $dateString
        project = @{
            id = $projectId
        }
        issuetype = @{
            id = $testExecutionIssueTypeId
        }
        customfield_10527 = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @($testsArray)
        customfield_10539 = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @($testPlanKey) 
    }
}
```

The two customfield properties are collections.  This is what I am seeing when I examine the HTTP for the request

```
{
    "fields":  {
                   "summary":  "Execution Monday, August 27, 2018 3:24 PM",
                   "customfield_10527":  "[\r\n    \"IC-54829\",\r\n    \"IC-54830\"\r\n]",
                   "customfield_10539":  "[\r\n    \"IC-54831\"\r\n]",
                   "project":  {
                                   "id":  "10401"
                               },
                   "issuetype":  {
                                     "id":  "10103"
                                 }
               }
}
```

If I use the -Compress flag the newline characters go away, but I am still getting the collection wrapped in quotes, and the internal quotes are escaped.  This is what is actually passed in the HTTP as the body with -Compress

```
{
    "fields":  {
                   "summary":  "Execution Monday, August 27, 2018 4:50 PM",
                   "customfield_10527":  "[\"IC-54829\",\"IC-54830\"]",
                   "customfield_10539":  "[\"IC-54831\"]",
                   "project":  {
                                   "id":  "10401"
                               },
                   "issuetype":  {
                                     "id":  "10103"
                                 }
               }
}
```

The two customfields are both collections that will contain one or more values and are built in an earlier step as arrays.  I need help converting it all, especially the customfields into the first json sample.

Answer (score 0):

So asked and no sooner answered.  I was making it harder than it has to be.  This works:

```
Write-Output 'Creating Test Execution'
$dateString = Get-Date -Format f
$createTestExecutionBody = @{
    fields = @{
        summary = 'Execution ' + $dateString
        project = @{
            id = $projectId
        }
        issuetype = @{
            id = $testExecutionIssueTypeId
        }
        customfield_10527 = @(
            $testsArray
        )
        customfield_10539 = @(
            $testPlanKey
        )
    }
}
```

I am sure there is probably a better way to do this, so I apologize for the quick ask and answer, but I would like to leave it here in case someone who knows powershell has the correct answer.